# Get Year-Month using simple one line code

Tags: php

how to get "Year-Month" from "2014-11-01" 
i can get those with following function

```
$date = "2014-11-01";
$year = date('Y', strtotime($date));
$month = date('F', strtotime($date));
echo $year.'-'.$month;//return 2014-11
```

OR

```
echo substr($this->getValue('PayMonth'),0,7);// return 2014-11
```

Now My question is can we do this using  **date()**  or any other PHP build-in function in one line

for example

```
 echo date('Y-m','2014-11-01');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

of course. Try this

```
echo date('Y-m',strtotime('2014-11-01'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [**`strtotime`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
echo date('Y-m',strtotime('2014-11-01'));
```

You can also do with [**`explode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like

```
$date_array = explode('-','2014-11-01');
echo $date_array[0].'-'.$date_array[1];
```

But make sure that your date format will be like "YY-MM-DD", if you want to use `explode`.

Comment: Thanks @Gautam ,i prefer the First one .